# Launching a second window upon a button press - tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

Im trying to set up a log in window in a simple app i´m making. On this app you have a username and a password to access to your profile, however, i cant manage to get the profile window to be opened.
More specifically i have a sign in button coded as:

```
register_button = Button(center_frame, padx=7, pady=2, text="Log In", font=(typeface, 10), bg=light_grey, fg="black", command =log)
```

log_in is my well log in function which checks the password and username to see if they are already registered and to pull up their user data:

```
def log():
    uname = entrylogun.get()
    log_pass = entrylogpa.get()
    hash1 = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(str(log_pass), rounds=1, salt_size=0)
    log_pass = 0
    log_complete = False
    with open("users.txt", "r") as users:
        if (uname + "" + hash1 + "") not in users.read():
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Verification Error",
                                        "The Password and Username combination "
                                        "\nentered is not valid, please try again")
        else:
            log_complete = True
```

then, i have later on:

```
if log_complete :
    profile_logged = open("" + uname + ".txt", "r")
    root1 = Tk()
    user = str(entrylogun.get())
    profile = open("" + uname + ".txt", "r+")
    root1.title("FedApp")
```

and it continues on and on...

but this wont open my second window upon pressing the log in button.

I have managed to get the second profile window to open but only by placing all the set up code for it inside the function and i feel that placing that much code inside a function is not propper.

basically im stuck at coding everything about the window there in the function, such as:

```
def log():
    global uname, log_pass, hash1, profile_logged, log_complete
    uname = entrylogun.get()
    log_pass = entrylogpa.get()
    hash1 = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(str(log_pass), rounds=1, salt_size=0)
    log_pass = 0
    log_complete = False
    with open("users.txt", "r") as users:
        if (uname + "" + hash1 + "") not in users.read():
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Verification Error",
                                        "The Password and Username combination "
                                        "\nentered is not valid, please try again")
        else:
            log_complete = True
            profile_logged = open("" + uname + ".txt", "r")
            root1 = Tk()
            user = str(entrylogun.get())
            profile = open("" + uname + ".txt", "r+")
            root1.title("FedApp")
            root1.geometry("600x600+534+70")
```

any ideas?

ive set up a minimum reproducible example:

working as it should (click on the small button):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

ventalalog = Tk()
ventalalog.title("FedeApp")
ventalalog.geometry("300x530+534+70")
background_color = "#36454F"
ventalalog.configure(bg=background_color)

log_complete = None
log_in_launch = None


def log():
    global profile_logged, log_complete
    log_complete = True
    if log_complete == False:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Verification Error",
                                    "The Password and Username combination "
                                    "\nentered is not valid, please try again")
    else:
        root1 = Tk()
        root1.title("FedApp")
        root1.geometry("600x600+534+70")


register_button = Button(command=log)
register_button.pack()

ventalalog.mainloop()
```

**NOT** working as it should:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

ventalalog = Tk()
ventalalog.title("FedeApp")
ventalalog.geometry("300x530+534+70")
background_color = "#36454F"
ventalalog.configure(bg=background_color)

log_complete = None
log_in_launch = None

def log():
    global log_complete, log_in_launch
    log_complete = True
    if log_complete == False :
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Verification Error",
                                        "The Password and Username combination "
                                        "\nentered is not valid, please try again")
    else:
        log_in_launch = True

register_button = Button(command =log)
register_button.pack()

if log_in_launch :
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.title("FedApp")
    root1.geometry("600x600+534+70")

ventalalog.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add a `print` statement after the `root1 = tk.Tk()`, if it prints something on the screen, then the window is created. To give a proper answer, we need a [mre] that we can run+test

Comment: Hey, @TheLizzard ive added the minimal reproducible example, its the exact same error

Comment: Use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` for window other than the root window.

Comment: thank you @acw1668 I'll be sure to check it as soon as possible!

Comment: @acw1668 adding that did not fix it :(. it still won't open unless I keep the set up code inside the function, even if I keep the root1 = Toplevel () inside the function

Comment: Why do you expect that checking `log_in_launch` outside the function works? When the checking is executed, `log_in_launch` has not been updated yet because `log()` has not been executed. Suggest you to search some tutorials on *"event-driven programming"*.

Comment: @acw1668 oh, i see of course, when i launch the program it runs through all the instructions past the check, yet it only launches the function upon the button press, so as the check was already executed and failed, it wont "wait" for me to press the button. Thank you so much, it makes so much more sense now what the issue is! I'm already looking into what you said. Thanks again for helping this newbie!